# Add image and label to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

How to add an image and label to my navigation on leftBarButtonItem?

[image]

I have assigned an image to my navigation item like this:

```
let notifButton  = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0) )

notifButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "notifications_white"), for: UIControlState.normal)
notifButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.notifButtonCLicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

let leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: notifButton)
self.UIViewController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let button =  UIButton(type: .custom)
          button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_right"), for: .normal)
          button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
          button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 53, height: 31)
          button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1, 32, 1, -32)//move image to the right
          let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 3, y: 5, width: 20, height: 20))
          label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 16)
          label.text = "title"
          label.textAlignment = .center
          label.textColor = .black
          label.backgroundColor =  .clear
          button.addSubview(label)
          let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
          self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Comment: thaks you save my day :)